# How to pass state from one component to another in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a movie type app and fetching data from an API.
I've made two separate components in my react project:

component one : Hero that displays movie poster

component two : Slider that displays all of the movies.

I've added a state variable to update the hero movie poster when each individual movie from the slider is clicked.

Originally, I had both components as the same component and that worked fine. I decided to separate them as I wanted to reuse the slider with another movie genre without having another hero section.

My question is how do I pass the setSelectMovie state variable from the HeroSlider to the Slider component to update the hero when a movie from the slider is clicked.

I have attached some references,
thanks

```js
import React from 'react'
import HeroSlider from '../components/HeroSlider';
import Slider from '../components/Slider'


function Movies({movies, topMovies, TvShows}) {


  
    return (

        <>

           <HeroSlider items={movies} />

           <Slider items={movies} />
           <Slider items={topMovies} />
           
        </>
    );
  }

  export default Movies
```

```js
import React, {useState }from 'react';
import FilterButton from './FilterButton';



function HeroSlider({items}) {


//state 
const [selectMovie, setSelectMovie] = useState(items.at(10));

   
   
return (

<>

    {/* Hero Section */}

        
    <div className="hero">


        <div className="bg-image">
            <img src={'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + selectMovie.backdrop_path} className="banner-img" />
        </div>

        <div className="movie-details">
            <h1>{selectMovie.original_title}</h1>
            <p>{selectMovie.overview}</p> 
            <button className='trailer-btn'>Watch Trailer</button>
        </div>
        
    </div>




{/*Originally had the slider here before breaking off into a seperate component (This Worked) */}

{/* 



<div className="media-scroller snaps-inline">
    
    {items.map((image, index) => (

                
        

        <div className="media-element">
            <img src={'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + image.poster_path} onClick={()=>{setSelectMovie(image)}} />
        </div>

   

   ))}
   </div>  */}

 


</>

    );
}


export default HeroSlider;
```

```js
import React, {useState }from 'react';



function Slider ({items}) {

   
   
return (

<>


    <h3 className='movie-genre'>Picked For You</h3>

        <div className="media-scroller snaps-inline">
    
    {items.map((image, index) => (



        <div className="media-element">
            <img src={'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + image.poster_path} onClick={()=>{setSelectMovie(image)}} />
        </div>

   

   ))}
   
   </div>



</>

    );
}


export default Slider;
```

Comment: Think you need to look at [Prettier](https://prettier.io/).

Comment: You might want to use context or state manager. Look into https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Your selectMovie state should create at the  Movies component and pass as params to all other component where you want to use

Comment: I have tried that. It doesn't have access to 'items' when used in Movies component. const [selectMovie, setSelectMovie] = useState(items.at(10));

Comment: I was having issues passing all variables as 'items ' to the movie component

Answer (score 2):

"Lift state up."  Basically, since the state is shared by these sibling components, it belongs in the parent component.  So `Movies` would host the state:

```
const [selectMovie, setSelectMovie] = useState();
```

Then these variables (the state value and its setter) can be passed as props to the child components:

```
<HeroSlider items={movies} selectMovie={selectMovie} setSelectMovie={setSelectMovie} />
<Slider items={movies} selectMovie={selectMovie} setSelectMovie={setSelectMovie} />
<Slider items={topMovies} selectMovie={selectMovie} setSelectMovie={setSelectMovie} />
```

They would then accept it as a prop:

```
function HeroSlider({items, selectMovie, setSelectMovie}) {
```

and:

```
function Slider ({items, selectMovie, setSelectMovie}) {
```

So any call to `setSelectedMovie` in a child component would update the state in the parent component, triggering a re-render of that parent and any child relying on that state.

Obviously if any given component doesn't use one of these two values then you don't *need* to pass both, just the one(s) it will use.

---

As you can see, this does start to make the code look a bit clogged up by repeating these values.  You can make use of higher-level state management systems as needed/preferred to abstract application-wide state away from individual components.  `useContext` or external systems like Redux are common approaches.

In those cases, the state itself exists outside of the component using it and each component which needs that state (the value and/or the setter) would use a hook to pull what it needs from that more global state.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest solution will be to use a Context Provider and share the setSelectMovie.

You wrap the components that need to share the Context and you are ready to go!:

Ref: [Context Provider](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)

Comment: Would be a better answer if you explained how to implement `Context` instead of just linking to documentation that can rot over time.

Comment: Ok, also going to try this solution. Thanks!